# CYPHER store order of node relationships of the same label when I create

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have multiple relationships that stem from a node. Each of these relationships are of the same label. The relationships point to a child node (not neccesarily unique). After I fetch all child nodes that link to the parent by this relationship label, I order them by a relationship property called trueindex. I then have an array of nodes that my client can iterate through in the correct sort order.

The problem comes when I try to "push, pop, unshift, etc..." onto this array. If I want to add a new relationship to the front of the order, I have to create a new relationship, use it to link the parent to the child node, then add a 0 value to the relationships trueindex property. The problem is that there already is a relationship with a trueindex value of zero and I need to perform somesort of casecading function that increments the trueindex of all other relationships (of the same type that all stem from that same parent node). I am trying to find a way to get this "array-like" index number functionality for free

The only way I can think to do so is to first delete all relationships of that particular label that stem from the parent. And then rewrite the entire array (with all the prexisting relationship that increment their trueindex by one) in order to reflect the correct order. This is fine for small cases but if I plan for a parent node to have a significant amount of relationships, then its a problem to rewrite the entire array (set of relationships) every time I want to add, remove by index, pop, etc and yet still maintain an order of relationships that stem from the parent node.

Does Neo4j have some sort of relationship feature to write to the correct order when creating new relationships?

I am very grateful for advise you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try keeping the child nodes in linked lists. The structure will look something like

```
(p:Parent)-[r1:CHILDREN]->(c1:Child)-[r2:NEXT]->(c2:Child)-[r3:NEXT]->(c3:Child)
```

This maintains the order of your child nodes and allows you to improve your interaction with the structure in two ways:

1. Inserting a new node into this structure only involves changes to the relationships 'before' and 'after' the place that node is going, as opposed to the entire structure. For example, to insert `newc` between `c1` and `c2`, you delete `r2`, create `newc` and create `:NEXT` relationships from `c1` to `newc` to `c2`. Analogous for other operations: all your alterations are now local within the structure.
2. You use relationships and their types to structure your data, instead of relationship properties. This is more flexible and almost always more performant (sometimes much more performant).

To read a single child from this structure you now use your `trueindex` to declare the depth in the linked list at which to find the node, i.e.

```
MATCH (parent:Parent {parentId: 1234})-[:CHILDREN]->()-[:NEXT*3]->(child)
RETURN child
```

and to retrieve a parent with all its children

```
MATCH (parent:Parent {parentId: 1234})-[:CHILDREN|NEXT*]->(child)
RETURN parent, COLLECT(child) as children
```

Comment: if a child node can have mutliple parent nodes (ie be featured in multiple 'arrays' of the same relationship label ) then how do you manage the :Next label to reflect membership to each parents' array?

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren When linked lists cross each other, that is, share a node, then to mark NEXT relations of each unique linked list, you can keep parent node's id as a property of NEXT for each linked list.

Comment: thank you @S.D. and jjaderberg. I am now trying to write an unshift query from your recommendations but I am having trouble with the conditional part. I tried CASE, but it seems to only be relevant for RETURN or WITH concrete values instead of allowing me to perform CREATE upon condition. I am trying to CREATE the first link in the linked list when this produces zero results: MATCH a-[rel:RELTYPE]->b n.id={_parentnodeid} and if it produces a result of 1, I'd like to perform the linked list maneuver described in the answer above. Thank you greatly for your help with this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SET` to increment or decrement properties of existing relations first.

The following example shifts `trueIndex` of existing relations and pushes a new relation (to an existing child node) at index 0:

```
MATCH (n:Root)-[r:HAS]->(c:Child) 
WHERE id(n) = 0 
SET r.trueIndex = r.trueIndex + 1
WITH n, min(r.trueIndex) as indexStart, max(r.trueIndex) as indexEnd
CREATE (n)-[r:HAS  {trueIndex:(indexStart-1)}]->(c:Child)
WHERE id(c) = 12
RETURN n,r,c
```

You can modify the query according to your needs.

Design wise, I agree with @jjaderberg 's answer, it would be simpler to keep a linked list to represent an array.