# Cypher Linked LIst: how to unshift and replace by index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a Linked List structure with Neo/Cypher as per the recomendation here: [CYPHER store order of node relationships of the same label when I create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263822/cypher-store-order-of-node-relationships-of-the-same-label-when-i-create/33267061#33267061)

```
(p:Parent)-[r1:PARENTID_RELTYPE]->(c1:Child)-[r2:PARENTID_RELTYPE]->(c2:Child)-[r3:PARENTID_RELTYPE]->(c3:Child)
```

But I am having trouble understanding the syntax for the required sequence of events in order to unshift new nodes onto the structure or replace a particular index with a different node.

Where I am confused is the part where I need to add the new node and repair the structure that keeps the old node still inside the linked list sturcture. There should be only one relationship of each type (PARENTID_RELTYPE) that stems from a Parent node; But there can be multiple relationships of different type from each parent. Child nodes can be featured multiple times within a LinkedList and a child node could be featured in a LinkedList of multiple Parents or in a LinkedList of the same parent but a different relationship type.

So one of three things could happen when I try to unshift:

1. There is no existing child that links to the parent by the PARENTID_RELTYPE
2. There already exists a child node that links to the parent by PARENTID_RELTYPE
3. There already exists a child node that links to the parent by PARENTID_RELTYPE and that child node is simply a duplicate of the child node I am attempting to unshift onto the linked list structure (in which case the intended result is to have the same child node in the zero and first indices of the linked list).

The answer url mentioned above helps me greatly in understanding how to read a linked list structure in Neo/Cypher but because of the alternative way for which conditionals are handled in cypher, I am having trouble understanding how to write to the structure (and also delete from he structure).

Below is my initial attempt to do so but I am somewhat baffled by what I need the syntax to do.

```
MATCH (a:%s {id: {_parentnodeid}}), (b:%s {id: {_id}})
MERGE  a-[relold:%s]->b
  ON CREATE
     SET relold.metadata = {_metaData}
  ON MATCH
     ...
```

I am very grateful for help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

In the following queries, for simplicity I pretend that:

- We find the `Parent` node of interest by name.
- The relationship type of current interest is `Foo`.

General Notes:

- The `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses find the sibling, if any, that should follow the child being inserted.
- The `FOREACH` clauses take care of linking the that sibling, if any, to the child being inserted, and then deletes the obsolete relationship to that sibling.

1. To *unshift* the `Child` having an `id` of `123` right after the `Parent` node:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Parent {name:"Fred"})
   OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[r:Foo]->(c:Child)
   WITH p, r, COLLECT(c) AS cs
   MERGE (cNew:Child {id:123})
   CREATE (p)-[rNew:Foo]->(cNew)
   FOREACH (x IN cs | 
     CREATE (cNew)-[:Foo]->(x)
     DELETE r)
   RETURN p, rNew, cNew;
   ```
2. To *insert* the `Child` node having an `id` of `123` at index 4 (i.e, make it the 5th child):

   ```
   MATCH (p:Parent {name:"Fred"})
   MATCH (p)-[:Foo*3]->()-[r:Foo]->(c:Child)
   OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r1:Foo]->(c1:Child)
   WITH c, r1, COLLECT(c1) AS c1s
   MERGE (cNew:Child {id:123})
   CREATE (c)-[rNew:Foo]->(cNew)
   FOREACH (x IN c1s | 
     CREATE (cNew)-[:Foo]->(x)
     DELETE r1)
   RETURN c, rNew, cNew;
   ```
3. To *replace* the `Child` at index 4 (i.e, the 5th child) with the `Child` having an `id` of `123`:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Parent { name:"Fred" })
   MATCH (p)-[:Foo*4]->(c0)-[r:Foo]->(c:Child)
   OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r1:Foo]->(c1:Child)
   WITH c0, r, c, r1, COLLECT(c1) AS c1s
   MERGE (cNew:Child { id:123 })
   CREATE (c0)-[rNew:Foo]->(cNew)
   DELETE r, c
   FOREACH (x IN c1s | 
      CREATE (cNew)-[:Foo]->(x)
      DELETE r1)
   RETURN c0, rNew, cNew;
   ```

   Note: The `DELETE r, c` clause always deletes the node being replaced (`c`). That is only suitable if that is what you actually want to happen, and will only succeed if `c` does not have relationships other than `r`. To explore how to address more specific needs, please ask a new question.

Comment: thank you greatly for your help cybersam. I have been trying these out and I successfully used 1.unshift. For 2.replace, why did you use MATCH (p)-[:Foo*4..4]->()-[r:Foo]->(c:Child) instead of MATCH (p)-[r:Foo*4]->(c:Child) ?

Also, is there a way to fall back in the event that there is no node at index 4? Where the cypher query will (fill the blanks) create nodes at indices 0 through 3 with some alternative static properties/label and eventually create the intended node at index 4? Or create nodes at indices 1 through 3 if there is already a child node linked with relationship Foo at index 0?

Comment: also, if MATCH (p)-[r:Foo*0]->(c:Child) produces no results for index 0, can the query fall back and (unshift) create the node relationship we originally planned to create at index 0 ?

Comment: I see that #2 is an *insert*, and not a *replace*. I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer (and corrected a bug in my insert operation as well). Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: thnx cybersam . can you pls offer guidance on some of my questions posted earlier today? I can make a new stackoverflow question post if you wish. i am very grateful for your help

Comment: I will try to find time to do that. I have also added a new `Note` under #3.

Comment: thank you greatly @cybersam I have added this related question in a separate post as you have advised: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447234/cypher-linkedlist-match-by-index-but-dont-know-how-to-compare-that-instead

Comment: Hi @cybersam I have been having trouble with the 3. replace statement. When I include this part DELETE r, c it gives me this error: "Relationship 254 has been deleted\" but when I remove DELETE r, c the prexisting r relationship remains as unintended. I am very grateful for help you could offer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following, your nodes may belong to multiple linked lists.  A simple 'next' relation is insufficient because when lists cross--share a child node--the 'next' relations will drag in all the downstream nodes of both lists.  So you're making the 'next' relations unique to each list by adding the id of the parent node. (Note using the metadata id may lead to issues down the road.)

So you might have a parent p1 whose id=1, and a unique relationship 'n_p1' to link its children, and a child 'c' whose id=21 you want to add.

For the parent with no child you could add your new child by:

```
MATCH (c {id:21}), (p {id:1}) WHERE NOT p-[:n_p1]->() MERGE p-[:n_p1]->c
```

And if the parent has one or more children, find the last one that's not the same as the one being added:

```
MATCH (c {id:21}), (p {id:1})-[:n_p1*1..5]->(cn) WHERE NOT cn-[:n_p1]->() AND NOT cn.id=c.id MERGE cn-[:n_p1]->c
```

Somebody else might have a better way, but you could UNION these together.  Remember the parts of a UNION must return the same columns, so just return the new child c.  The whole thing might look like this:

```
MATCH (c {id:21}), (p {id:1}) WHERE NOT p-[:n_p1]->() MERGE p-[:n_p1]->c return c UNION MATCH (c {id:21}), (p {id:1})-[:n_p1*1..5]->(cn) WHERE NOT cn-[:n_p1]->() AND NOT cn.id=c.id MERGE cn-[:n_p1]->c return c;
```