# Cypher LinkedList Match by index but "Don't know how to compare that." instead

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having trouble with MATCH by index and I am hoping you can help. Related discussion can be found at this post: [Cypher Linked LIst: how to unshift and replace by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306838/cypher-linked-list-how-to-unshift-and-replace-by-index)

First I run the following unshift query three times in order to populate the linked list with relationships and nodes

```
MATCH (p {id: '123A'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[r:Foo]->(c)
WITH p, r, COLLECT(c) AS cs
MERGE (cNew {
    id:'456B'    // and '789C' and 'WXYZ'
})
CREATE (p)-[rNew:Foo {
    isFavorite:false,
    isOpen:false,
    currenttab:'all',
    currentdate:2015-10-30T07:00:00.000Z
}]->(cNew)
FOREACH (x IN cs | 
    CREATE (cNew)-[:Foo {
        isFavorite:r.isFavorite,
        isOpen:r.isOpen,
        currenttab:r.currenttab,
        currentdate:r.currentdate
    }]->(x)
    DELETE r)
RETURN p, rNew, cNew
```

Afterwords I can fetch the output with this query so that I can see that I have three elements in my linkedlist array under the relationship label Foo

```
MATCH ()-[r:`language-arts_ALLRESOURCES`]->() RETURN r

isFavorite  false
isOpen  false
currenttab  all
currentdate 2015-10-30T07:00:00.000Z

isFavorite  false
isOpen  false
currenttab  all
currentdate 2015-10-30T07:00:00.000Z

isFavorite  false
isOpen  false
currenttab  all
currentdate 2015-10-30T07:00:00.000Z
```

I then try to query the first index with this cypher query

```
MATCH (p { id:"123A" })
MATCH (p)-[:Foo*1]->()-[r:Foo]->(c)
RETURN c
```

But I am coming up with the error below:

```
Don't know how to compare that. Left: [:Foo[8258]

{isFavorite:false,isOpen:false,currenttab:"all",currentdate:"2015-10-

30T07:00:00.000Z"}] ($colon$colon); Right: :Foo[8260]

{isFavorite:false,isOpen:false,currenttab:"all",currentdate:"2015-10-

30T07:00:00.000Z"} (RelationshipProxy)
```

I tried fetching with this query:

```
MATCH (p { id:"123A" })
MATCH (p)-[:Foo*2]->(c)
RETURN c
```

and this is the output that comes back

```
id  789C // which is index 1
```

I also have some slight confusion as to whether index 1 should be fetched with the integer 0 or 1 or 2 but that confusion I am sure can be sorted out once I get passed this 'Don't know how to compare that.' error. Please help me with guidance as to the right way to fetch effectively by index and avoid the error I listed above.

I am very grateful for your help

** NOTE **

After reading cybersam's answer, I have run the following tests on the linked list structure mentioned above that contains three elements

This query returns the child at the index 0 position:

```
MATCH (p { id:'123A' })
MATCH (p)-[:Foo*0]->()-[r:Foo]->(c)
RETURN c
```

This query returns the child at the index 1 position:

```
MATCH (p { id:'123A' })
MATCH (p)-[:Foo]->()-[r:Foo]->(c)
RETURN c
```

This query returns the "Don't know how to compare that." error

```
MATCH (p { id:'123A' })
MATCH (p)-[:Foo*1]->()-[r:Foo]->(c)
RETURN c
```

This query returns the child at the index 2 position:

```
MATCH (p { id:'123A' })
MATCH (p)-[:Foo*2]->()-[r:Foo]->(c)
RETURN c
```

I am assuming this last one works for anything >= 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher seems to be confused by the (as far as I can tell) legal `[:Foo*1]` syntax. If you just used `[:Foo]` instead, which logically equivalent, you would have avoided the error.

But, actually, the way to get the index 0 child is:

```
MATCH (p { id:"123A" })
MATCH (p)-[r:Foo]->(c)
RETURN c;
```

Or, to get the 0 index child in a more generic way, this will work. This generic pattern *should always* work for any index (by replacing `0` with the desired index), but there seems to be a bug (as stated above) in Cypher when using `1`:

```
MATCH (p { id:"123A" })
MATCH (p)-[:Foo*0]->()-[r:Foo]->(c)
RETURN c
```

I have created [neo4j issue 5799](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5799) for this.

Comment: thank you greatly for your help @cybersam I added an edit note to the original question to further describe the issue. i very much appreciate you guiding me through these questions and gaining neo/cypher skills